# VIVADO HLS: How to declare "total width of the variable" in Arbitrary Precision Types?

Tags: c, vivado-hls

I am working with XILINX VIVADO HLS in which I need to run C/C++ codes with "Arbitrary Precision Types". So, I have gone through the "Arbitrary Precision Types" topics in UG902 Xilinx guidebook.But I am not clear on the topic. I don't know how to initialize"total width of the variable". Can anyone explain me with examples?

```
 int#W,
 uint#W
```

The number #W specifies the total width of the variable being declared.
Suppose my array size is 102 (1D-array) or 102x204 (2d array). How u will declare "total width of the variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of an arbitrary precision type refer to the number of bits in the variable, and it is orthogonal to storing precision types in an array.

For instance, if you want 102 elements of 4 bits, you would use:

```
int4 array[102];
```